# javascript (trying to copy windows.location without success)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like I've fallen down the rabbit hole and I imagine there's a simpler overall strategy, but here I am.

I want to allow users to sort a given set of results AFTER they've already filtered those results.  I want to keep the original filters in place while adding a new one (sort).  I wanted to avoid having to create hidden inputs with the original filters and then submit the form via a click event handler on the sort links.

What I tried to do instead was read the window.location and concatanate the GET parameters with my new sort parameter.  It worked, except that it kept concatanating with each sort click.  I only want one sort variable added per click.  I tried a regex solution and it's not working.  It keeps changing the windows.location variable and redirecting the page.

I'm new to js and I don't know how to deepcopy strings...or the equivalent.  How can I solve this issue? I'm also new to js regex, so pardon my naivety

```
   $('div#sort ul a').each(function(){
    var currentPath=window.location;
    currentPath=currentPath.replace(/sort=\w+$/,'sort='+$(this).attr('data-sort'));
    $(this).attr('href',currentPath)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location` is not a a string, it's a "URL object". You can force it into a string like this:

> var currentPath=window.location+'';

Comment: or `window.location.toString()`

Comment: perfect.  That fixed it, thanks!  Generally speaking, does the overall method I described above seem reasonably efficient? I'm new to this

Comment: @Brendan: It's OK. Don't worry about efficiency until it becomes an issue

Comment: the `window.location` object has a property called `href` where the entire URL string is stored. no need to force anything. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx